# How can I sum variable of js and variable of php?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to sum variable of js and php. below are my sapmle codes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.fonkTopla = function() {
var toplam = 1;
this.each(function() {
   var deger = fonkDeger($(this).val());

   //get the data attr value
   var diff = $(this).data('diff');
   var paid_val = $(this).closest('tr').find('.paid').val();

   //On based on data attribute, if the input field is paid, do not multiply,
   if(!diff){
   toplam *= deger;

   //take the result minus paid field
   total = toplam - paid_val;
   }
});
return total;
};


function fonkDeger(veri) {
    return (veri != '') ? parseInt(veri) : 1;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name^="fiyat"]').bind('keyup', function() {

   //for multiple tr, get the closest tr field value to calculate and display
   $(this).closest('tr').find('.toplam').html( $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="fiyat"]').fonkTopla());
});
});
</script>

<td><span class="toplam"></span> RWF</td>
```

I want to display toplam variable of js + $credit variable of php which stores previous credit amount.
Example

```
<td><span class="toplam + <?php $credit;?>"></span> RWF</td>
```

Comment: Where is the Java code?

Comment: Well, if JS is loaded after PHP, then you can pass php value into html tag and then in javascript access this html tag by id for example and do the sum and print it into this html tag